# Code Contracts: IEnumerator<T>.GetEnumerator() weird inherited contract?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ienumerable, code-contracts

I am using [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) together with the [Code Contracts Editor Extensions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/85f0aa38-a8a8-4811-8b86-e7f0b8d8c71b) VS2010 add-in. I have a class that implements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, and I've implemented an iterator block for the `GetEnumerator()` method. Above it, I can see the following inherited contract:

[image: ensures result != null ensures result.Model == ((IEnumerable)this).Model [Pure] public IEnumerator(of IBaseMessage) GetEnumerator() {]

I understand the first and third contract requirement - `GetEnumerator()` must never return a null, and it must never cause a side-effect. But what does the second contract requirement mean? What is this `Model` property of `IEnumerator<T>` and of `IEnumerable`?

**EDIT:** As Damien_The_Unbeliever pointed out in his comment, the contract for `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>` are located in a seperate file, a Contracts Reference Assembly. Using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/), in the disassembly of the contract of those two interfaces (the full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/8sAmk7ee)), you can see the following:

```
[return: Fresh]
[Escapes(true, false), Pure, GlobalAccess(false)]
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    IEnumerator enumerator;
    Contract.Ensures((bool) (Contract.Result<IEnumerator>() != null), null, "Contract.Result<IEnumerator>() != null");
    Contract.Ensures((bool) (Contract.Result<IEnumerator>().Model == this.Model), null, "Contract.Result<IEnumerator>().Model == this.Model");
    Contract.Ensures((bool) (Contract.Result<IEnumerator>().CurrentIndex == -1), null, "Contract.Result<IEnumerator>().CurrentIndex == -1");
    return enumerator;
}
```

Interestingly, there's an additional contract in `GetEnumerator()` that isn't displayed by the editor extention:

```
Contract.Result<IEnumerator>().CurrentIndex == -1
```

And some additionaly mysteries (such as the `Fresh`, `Escapes` and `GlobalAccess` attributes).

Comment: I can't help you, but thanks for pointing me towards some areas of interest. The `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` types used by code contracts are loaded from C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Contracts\Contracts\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.Contracts.dll (location may vary), and these versions of the interfaces (and their associated contract classes) have more members than the "actual" interfaces from mscorlib. But even having read through the contract annotations, I've no idea what the purpose of Model is.

Comment: @Damien: Thanks, I've edited the question per your new information.

Comment: Is that `IEnumerator` return type in the contract the real `IEnumerator` interface or a class with the same name? If it's the interface I don't even understand why it compiles.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: No, mscorlib.Contracts.dll defines its own `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` which includes all the original members plus those extra properties (they do not inherit from the original interfaces). I'm not sure how it works seeing as their interfaces are completely separate and unrelated types as far as the Common Type System is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

Having taken a second look at the code/contracts loaded from C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Contracts\Contracts.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.Contracts.dll (as referenced in my comment).

I believe it can be safely ignored for your implementation. What it seems to relate to is that it's trying to define a contract such that (effectively) once you're iterating with your `IEnumerator` object, it will return a certain number of elements. These elements are effectively "snapshotted" when the call to GetEnumerator has returned, and calls to Reset and MoveNext can only iterate over the same set of elements.

I think it's trying to give some immutability guarantees. I've no idea if we can write these same kind of contracts ourselves - it uses the `ContractModel` attribute, which doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, so far as I can find.

---

Concerning immutablility, etc:

I was mostly looking at the contract for MoveNext on the returned IEnumerator object - basically, it's saying that MoveNext can't change the Model property (that we know was the same Model assigned to it by GetEnumerator), and that the CurrentIndex property is varied between 0 and Model.Length. After that it's just gut feeling/guesswork. I can't point to anything else in the contract assembly that gives me any more info.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you reached that conclusion from the contract disassembly, care to elaborate? Could all those extra properties be generated by the compiler when it converts an iterator block to a regular method using [CPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style)?